# Java - Recursion Program - way to convert an inputted base to base 10 on a given number

Tags: java, recursion

I am given a non-recursive method, that I need to modify to make recursive.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class BaseN {

   public static final int BASEN_ERRNO = -1;

   public static void main(String[] argv) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("enter number followed by base (e.g. 237 8): ");
      int number = input.nextInt();
      int base = input.nextInt();

      BigInteger answer = basen(number, base);
      System.out.println(number + " base-" + base + " = " + answer);
   }
   static BigInteger basen(int number, int base ) {

        List<Integer> remainder = new ArrayList<>();

        int count = 0;
        String result = "";
        while( number != 0 ) {
            remainder.add( count, number % base != 0 ? number % base : 0 );
            number /= base;
            try {
                result += remainder.get( count );
            } catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new BigInteger( new StringBuffer( result ).reverse().toString() );
    }
}
```

It's converting it to base 10 then the given base. I need it to convert to the given base first then base 10.

---

UPDATE:
I changed around Caetano's code a bit and think I am closer.

```
static String basen(int number, int base) {

String result = String.valueOf(number % base);
int resultC;
String resultD;

int newNumber = number / base;

if (newNumber != 0)
    result += basen(newNumber, base);
if (newNumber == 0)
  resultC = Integer.parseInt(result);
  resultD = Integer.toString(resultC);

return resultD;
```

Now when I compile it it gives me an error it says:

```
BaseN.java:49: error: variable resultC might not have been initialized
  resultD = Integer.toString(resultC);
```

Am I on the right track here? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your method doesn't compiles. Is that your problem? Or you want to ask something else?

Comment: It compiles for me. I have all of util, math, and io imported. The user will be asked to input 2 numbers. The first one will be the number I need to do the arithmetic to, and the second number will be the base I need to convert the first number to. For example The input would be "512 6"
number = 512
base = 6

Now I need to convert 512 to base 6, then base 10.  My program outputs 2212. IT converts it to base 10 then base 6. It should output 188, which is the result if it were to calculate base 6 first followed by base 10

Comment: So, in other words, you want to parse the input number using the given base, and then output it as a decimal; is that right? It's much easier if you input the number as a string, instead of parsing it as a decimal integer and then trying to re-parse it as a different base.

Comment: I want to convert the number to base-X then convert it to base-10 using recursion. For example, if number = 512 && base = 6 then answer = 188.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what you are asking for.

I can only assume that you want to convert from a given base to base 10. The way that you would do this is explained in this page here: [MathBits introduction to base 10](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Introduction/tobase10.htm).

The way explained in this is simple. For each digit in the number you get the base to the power of the position of the digit(reversed) and multiply that by whatever the digit is. Then add all the results. So 237 in base 8 would be

(8^2 * 2) + (8^1 * 3) + (8^0 * 7) = 159

Now you will run in to a problem when you do this with bases higher then 10 since the general notation for digits above 9 is alphabetical letters. However you could get around this by having a list of values such as [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F] and compare the digits with this list and get the index of the location of that digit as the number.

I hope this is what you were asking for.

---

Now then this is code that does what you want it to do. Get a number in a given base and convert it to base 10. However I don't see why you need to use a recursive method for this. If this is some kind of school task or project then please tell us the details because I don't personally see a reason to use recursion. However the fact that your question asks us to modify the code up top to make it recursive then it makes much more sense. Since that code can be edited to be as such.

```
   public static final int BASEN_ERRNO = -1;

   public static void main(String[] argv) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("enter number followed by base (e.g. 237 8): ");
      String number = input.next();
      int base = input.nextInt();

      int answer = basen(number, base);

      System.out.println(number + " base-" + base + " = " + answer);
   }

   private static int basen(String number, int base ) {

       int result = 0;

       for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
           int num = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(i, i + 1));

           result += Math.pow(base, number.length() - i - 1) * num;
       }

       return result;

   }
```

However what I think that you want is actually this which shows recursion but instead of converting from base given to base 10 it converts from base 10 to base given. Which is exactly what the code you showed does but uses recursion. Which means '512 6' will output '2212'

```
public static final int BASEN_ERRNO = -1;

public static void main(String[] argv) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("enter number followed by base (e.g. 237 8): ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int base = input.nextInt();

    String answer = new StringBuffer(basen(number, base)).reverse().toString();

    System.out.println(number + " base-" + base + " = " + answer);
}

static String basen(int number, int base) {

    String result = String.valueOf(number % base);

    int newNumber = number / base;

    if (newNumber != 0)
        result += basen(newNumber, base);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The first one will be the number I need to do the arithmetic to, and the second number will be the base I need to convert the first number to. For example The input would be "512 6" number = 512 base = 6 Now I need to convert 512 to base 6, then base 10. My program outputs 2212. IT converts it to base 10 then base 6. It should output 188, which is the result if it were to calculate base 6 first followed by base 10

Comment: I believe that is what my answer explains, is it not? You said you want 512 which is a number in base 6 to be converted to base 10. Following my logic. 6^2 * 5 = 36 * 6 = 180,    6^1 * 1 = 6 * 1 = 6,    6^0 * 2 = 1 * 2 = 2 which results that all numbers added together is 180 + 6 + 2 which is 188. Would you like a code example instead?

Comment: Okay, I kind of understand what you mean now.  How would I put that into a recursive equation based on what I already have.

Comment: I edited the answer to show you the codes. However I will state here what is said up top which is that there is no reason to create a recursive method for what you want to do, but there is a reason to create a recursive method for the first code you showed us which would make a lot more sense if you were asked to make it recursive. Are you 100% sure that you want to convert from base-X to Base-10 and not the other way around.

Comment: I need it recursive for a school use. Coded like your second example, but I need it to do the math like in your first example. If 512 6 is answered the output should be 188.  If 314 8 is entered the output should be 204.

Comment: Yes, I want to convert it to base X to base 10.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't really think of way using recursion using the method I have used. I am truly sorry for that. That being said you should try to re-arrange my code in some way to make it so that it uses recursion if that is what you need to do. I cannot really help you any further.

Comment: Thank you for your time, anyway. It was valued.

Comment: I changed your second one around a bit, However, I still cannot get it to work.

Comment: Check the Update above, please.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it recursively. Thank you everyone who provided help. I ended up using Math.pow on the base and put the length of the number -1 for how it would be exponentially increased.  Math.pow puts the result in double format so I just converted it back to an int.  My professor gave me 100% for this answer, so I'd imagine it would work for others too.

```
public static int basen(int number, int base) {

  String numberStr;
  int numberL;
  char one;
  String remainder;
  int oneInt;
  int remainderInt;
  double power;
  int powerInt;

  numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
  numberL = numberStr.length();
  if(numberL > 1){
     one = numberStr.charAt(0);
     remainder = numberStr.substring(1);
     oneInt = Character.getNumericValue(one);
     remainderInt = Integer.parseInt(remainder);

     power = Math.pow(base, (numberL - 1));
     powerInt = (int)power;
     return ((oneInt * powerInt) + (basen(remainderInt, base)));
  }
  else{
     return number;
  }
 }
```